# how to solve y = |Sin(x^x)/2^(((x^x)-pi/2)/pi)| in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, equation, pi

how to solve this question in MATLAB?

Create an array for x from 0 to 2π with 1000 elements and graph the following equation:
y = |Sin(x^x)/2^(((x^x)-pi/2)/pi)|

I have tried but it didn't work:

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000);

y = abs(sin(x.^x)/(2.^(((x.^x) - pi / 2)/ pi)));

plot(x,y)
```

Comment: The first `/` should be `./`. Nice-looking function BTW

Comment: thanks.. it's worked fine now